# Is 15mm pipe adequate for a bathroom shower?

Tags: shower

I am currently fitting a new shower valve.

The supply to the bathroom is 22mm for both hot and cold branching with 15mm to washbasin, toilet and existing shower valve (H&C).

The new valve is dual head, rainfall and conventional both 15mm.

The new valve inputs are 3/4". Should I run 22mm as far as I can or will the existing 15mm do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you can replace the branching sections of 15mm to where they change to 22mm, there's no reason to run any 22mm. Stick with the 15mm.

Comment: I agree. The limiting factor will be the shower head. Two 15mm lines bring plenty of flow unless the household pressure is poor.